# I want if else on focusOut in an input, if save btn is clicked do something else do something else

Tags: javascript

I'm calling this function onclick of an edit btn and i want on **focus out** of the input box there should be to options if the **save btn** is clicked or **anywhere else**

```
function saveChanges() {
    var field = document.getElementById('edit_qual');
    var save_btn = document.getElementById('save_btn');

    field.addEventListener ("focusOut", function() {
        if (save_btn.clicked==true) {
            alert("saved"); //or something
        }
        else {
            alert("Not saved")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i correctly understand your issue. I have done a working Fiddle. When the Button was clicked and you go in the Textarea and focus out the Alert says "save". Otherwise "not save"

```
function saveChanges() {
var field = document.getElementById('edit_qual');
var save_btn = document.getElementById('save_btn');
var clicked = false
save_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clicked = true
})
field.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
    if (clicked == true) {
        alert("saved"); //or something
    } else {
        alert("Not saved")
    }
})
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfdu7cp8/2/)

Comment: appreciated !! its working but not on the first attempt. I mean when save btn is clicked the focus gets out and else part runs and _clicked_ var is initialized then on the second attempt the if part runs. and one more thing, only if part runs further because clicked has true value.